# MS Access transaction committing but not saved to database

Tags: ms-access, transactions, workspace

I am using MS Access front end to MySQL back end, replicated in a MASTER-2-MASTER set up. There are three users on separate machines, all with their own installation of the front end, all querying the database at the same time and inserting data into three Innodb tables in MySQL.

I have a transaction set up in MS Access whereby I make a call to the insert function for table1, retrieve the variable "k" value and then call two more functions that insert into both Table2 and Table3 using "k" as the foreign key. Once I commit the transaction in Ms Access, a report prints the new rows from the three tables on one report.

The command to open the report comes after the committrans and uses the variable "k" as the where condition as follows:

"[Id] = " & k

The issue is that roughly 2 out of every 100 processes successfully print the report with all of the information from the joined tables as if everything was added and committed to the database successfully, but upon looking in the database, the records are not found.

After checking the MySQL database, there seems to be gaps in the primary key, which I assume only happens if something was actually there and then deleted, however I have checked the MySql binlogs and do not see a delete command executed on any of the tables.

Would there be any issues using Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0) to start the transaction, but then using Set db = CurrentDb when opening the recordset? Any other ideas?

Following is the current flow from Access to MySQL and back:

IN ACCESS                                                                            IN MYSQL
BeginTrans
  --------------------------------------------> PassThrough LOCK TABLES
  --------------------------------------------> PassThrough Insert into table1
  k <------------------------------------------   return last_insertid from table1 into k
  --------------------------------------------> Passthrough Insert into table2 foreignkey = k
  --------------------------------------------> Passthrough Insert into table3 foreignkey = k
 optional -----------------------------------> Passthrough Insert into table4 foreignkey = k
 optional -----------------------------------> Passthrough Insert into table5 foreignkey = k
 optional -----------------------------------> Passthrough Insert into table6 foreignkey = k
 Local Insert into table7 foreignkey = k
 Local Insert into table8 foreignkey = k
 --------------------------------------------> PassThrough UNLOCK TABLES
CommitTrans
Print report (recordsource = linked table1 filter on k)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use transaction with external tables may be the data will be lost, try using a compatible technology like sql server.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ivan, but I can't. I am not in a position to suggest changing the database for this client based on budget. Also, I'm quite sure that no data is being lost since the report, which is based on the linked tables within Access, prints with data from the 3 separate tables, while the k value comes directly from the stored procedure via a pass through query. One would assume that if the report prints with the new data, the data was successfully added to Mysql via the pass through and subsequently updated into the linked tables. But when I check the tables in Mysql, no data.

Comment: Transactions in Access are ONLY for Access. Access transactions HAVE NOTHING to do with Oracle, SQL server or in your case MySQL. You have to use server side "MySQL" code to do this, and as such this would be a MySQL feature and has NOTHING to do with the client software. Thus the use of begin trans inside of Access will not work with MySQL and not even with SQL server. As such just like store procedures in MySQL are MASSIVE different then the ones in Access, so are MySQL transactions. You have to call MySQL routines and BeginTrans is ONLY for native Access tables, not server based ones.

Comment: Thank you @Albert. I was aware of that fact, therefore I have each MySql procedure return "true" if it succeeds or "false" if it fails  and I exit the Access transaction with a RollBack without CommitTrans. Are you suggesting that in my case, the MySql procedures will commit to the MySql DB even if something fails at the end of the Access transaction but before CommitTrans?

Comment: The MySQL routines that rollback will not commit data. As long as you keep in mind that linked tables to MySQL don’t work with BeingTrans, then you should be ok. This means and suggests you should MOVE the pass-though quires OUT of the BeingTrans/CommitTrans code block. So you should have BeingTrans, and then your local insert to table 7 and 8 and then commit. Placing OTHER commands such as the pass-though stuff ONLY serves to confuse this issue.